# Python serial ( pySerial) can write but not read data ( Windows 11, Python 3.10 )?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

My Python script can send a download command over a Bluetooth serial COM port, but cannot receive data?

- Windows 11
- Python 3.10.7
- Serial.Version: 3.5

code:

```
import serial

print("serial.VERSION: %s" % (serial.VERSION))
BluetoothSerialPort = 'COM9'
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.timeout = 1.0
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.port = BluetoothSerialPort
ser.open()

# Start binary data download
# This works. Bluetooth device responds by replying
# with a one line ASCII response,
# followed by 10 KB of binary file data ( non ASCII )
ser.write(b'download')

# packetBytes is always zero ??? 
downloading = True
while downloading:
    packetBytes = ser.read(1)
    print("packetBytes.: %d" % (len(packetBytes)))
```

This program prints "packetBytes.: 0" at the timeout rate of 1.0 second.

```
serial.VERSION: 3.5
packetBytes.: 0
packetBytes.: 0
packetBytes.: 0
...
```

Why would write work, but not read?

- The Bluetooth device receives the download command.
- I can see the data being sent from the Bluetooth device.
- Using a Windows Serial Terminal connected to COM9, I can send command and receive data as expected

Python read never returns anything?

Comment: I'm unclear what the evidence you have is that proves that the Bluetooth device receives the download command and sends data when you run the python script.

Comment: I can see my Bluetooth device printing in it's own debug console, in response to the 'download' command received from the Python script.  I can see Bluetooth device printing  progress statements as it is dumping the binary data and transmitting.  This is evidence Bluetooth device received the 'download' command sent by Python.  However, it is not evidence that the binary data being transmitted was actually received on the Windows 11 COM port.  I will return to using serial bluetooth serial terminal to first verify it can receive data.  Perhaps it is a Bluetooth serial port connect problem.

Comment: Please try setting each value of `rts`, `rtscts`, `dtr`, `dsrdtr` appropriately. [pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)